# Time difference in days between two transaction by account number

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
        accountid   txnid   txndate              
        1            176    2015-11-27 00:00:00  
        1            177    2015-12-27 00:00:00  
        472          202    2015-12-01 00:00:00  
        472          203    2015-12-10 00:00:00
```

I have the above table structure, 
Need to  find the date difference between two transaction date for individual account id

expected output

```
     accountid  txnid   txndate               diffdays_trans
        1   176 2015-11-27 00:00:00     0
        1   177 2015-12-27 00:00:00     30
        472 202 2015-12-01 00:00:00     0
        472 203 2015-12-10 00:00:00     10
```

As txnid 176 is the first transaction there is no time difference, txn 177 for account # 1  has appeared after 1 month so the time difference is 30 days,
similarly for account # 472  trans# 202  is the first transaction hence it will be 0 days, and trans#203 appeared after 10 days hence days diff is 10

Comment: you can use lead function to get next transaction date.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output?

Comment: Please correct your input data for the same.

Answer (score 1):

To find the difference between two transaction date for individual account id:

Using [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (accountid INT,  txnid INT,  txndate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (accountid, txnid, txndate) VALUES
(1  , 176, '2015-11-27 00:00:00'),  
(1  , 177, '2015-12-27 00:00:00'),  
(472, 202, '2015-12-01 00:00:00'),  
(472, 203, '2015-12-10 00:00:00'); 

SELECT accountid, txnid, txndate, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, NextDateTime, txndate), 0) AS [diffdays_trans]
FROM (
    SELECT accountid, txnid, txndate, 
           LAG (txndate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY accountid ORDER BY accountid) AS NextDateTime
    FROM @TestTable
) AS Q
```

it will result as:

```
accountid   txnid   txndate                  diffdays_trans
-------------------------------------------------------------
1           176     2015-11-27 00:00:00.000  0
1           177     2015-12-27 00:00:00.000  30
472         202     2015-12-01 00:00:00.000  0
472         203     2015-12-10 00:00:00.000  9
```

Comment: Please find the updated answer. `SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, 2015-12-10, 2015-12-01)` will result as 9 only. If you want include the specific date too you may use `DATEDIFF(DAY, 2015-12-10, 2015-12-01) +1` to get the output as `10`

Comment: I am testing your query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use lead function to get next transaction date.

```
select *, lead(txndate,1) over(partition by accountid order by accountid) nextdate, datediff(day,txndate, lead(txndate,1) over(partition by accountid order by accountid))days_diff
    from #tbl
```

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded  I am getting this error, Is there a way to overcome this...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any knowledge on Java.

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham Go through this link to get what  error it is: https://www.baeldung.com/java-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded